# How to setup the starting form of a winforms project in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Does anybody know how to setup the starting form of a winforms project in Visual Studio 2010? I have ridden to go to Project Properties and change Startup Object, but in dowpdownlist the only options available were "(None)" and "ProjectName.Program.cs". The "program.cs" is my default code file. Please help me. (Im working in C#)

Comment: What type of the project do you have? Console app?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In your Program.cs, there is line like:

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

where you can substitute the form you'd like to start. If you change `Form1` to another Form class, your project will start with that one.

Answer (score 4):

It is not only in Program.cs. It is in any class where exists a "static Main()" function.
Programs.cs is made for you by the IDE on certain type of project. It's not a must.

Example:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.DoEvents();
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
```

The project properties, tab: "Application" show a dropdown with every class that as a static Main() function. You could choose the one you want from there.

Answer (score 4):

in visual studio
on the menu bar:
project > project properties > start up form : select the form within your project that you want to run on start up.

Answer (score -2):

Go to 'Tools' and click on 'Options'.

Next, go on the 'Startup' option within the 'Environment' category, and select 'Show Start Page' from the drop down menu.