# Window forms inside project

Tags: windows, forms, project, computer-science

I created a Windows Form application and within the project I have several forms (form1 (form created when creating the project), registration, application content, logging in). I want to change the order in which the forms are displayed when I start the project, that is, I do not want the "Form1" form to be displayed first, but the "Registration" form and so on. Is that possible?

Comment: This has an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6981091/244361

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to setup the starting form of a winforms project in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981045/how-to-setup-the-starting-form-of-a-winforms-project-in-visual-studio-2010)